# How to set media queries for a scroll event

Tags: reactjs

I need to make media queries for my navbar that change class on vertical scroll. It works on desktop mode just as I like, on mobile device the class don't change at the right height.

I'm fairly new in react and haven't found any thing useful to alter my code for the wanted effect.

```
  class navbar extends React.Component {

  state = {
      color: 'white',
  }
  listenScrollEvent = e => {
      if (window.scrollY > 882) {
          this.setState({color: 'black', background: 'white', transition: '.2s', boxShadow: '0px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.1)'})
      } else {
          this.setState({color: 'white', background: 'transparent', transition: '.2s', boxShadow: '0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5)'})
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent)
  }


  render () {

    return (


    <nav className="navbar" style={{color: this.state.color, background: this.state.background, transition: this.state.transition, boxShadow: this.state.boxShadow }}>
        <div className="navbar__body">
          <ToggleMenu click={this.props.menuClickHandler} />
          <h2 className="navbar__logo">j.p<span>Cazeau</span></h2>
          <ul className="navbar__items">
            <li><NavLink to="/"><i className="fab fa-facebook-f" style={{color: this.state.color}} /></NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/"><i className="fab fa-twitter" style={{color: this.state.color}} /></NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/"><i className="fab fa-youtube" style={{color: this.state.color}} /></NavLink></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
export default navbar
```

Expecting to have the navbar class change on right heights on diffrent devices, mobile, landscape etc..

I added a codepen 
https://codepen.io/jpCazeau/pen/VgxxOL

Comment: Can you share the part of render where you use `this.state.color`?  As a way of debugging, you might need to output `window.scrollY` to the screen to see what value you should use in the listener on smaller screens.

Comment: Also, what is the 882 number based on?  If you're looking for something more responsive, it would be better not to hard-code this value and calculate it by measuring some other element if possible.  Depending on the structure of your components, you might be able to use `refs` for this.

Comment: the number 882 I belived it is when classes changes on scrollY position.